# Apache spark get number from list of bounds

Tags: python, list, apache-spark

I have a list of numbers going into a Spark function.  Each number is a lower bound for a category... E.g,

```
6.252   1
5.502   2
4.387   3
```

I then input a number into this function.  Basically I want to see which index of the list it falls into.  So 8.5 would fall into first category, 6.1 would go in the 2nd.  I tried working with absolute values using

```
myIndex = list.index(min(list, key=lambda x:abs(x-inputVal))))
```

but this could give me the wrong bucket as it only looks for proximity. I also thought about brute force iterating through the list and grabbing current value and next value but there has to be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bisect module:

```
import bisect

breaks = sorted([4.387, 5.502, 6.252])

len(breaks) - bisect.bisect_left(breaks, 4.3)
```